# Full and Partial Matching of Sets

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

I have several sets of the same type [Y, M, D] and am trying to write a function to search these sets and return an array of the available sets that fit my parameters.

ReturnedSets = return_matches(Y,M,D);

I want the three parameters of the function return_matches to be optional. Which means any combination of values can be used to return the sets.

For example, one could write - return_matches(13,null,2); - and the function would look for all sets that contain [13, anyValue, 2];

I'm writing this in PHP, to allow users to manage dated files on my website, but I'd like to be able to use this function again for other uses.

Thanks!

edit: (This, or variations of this, is all I can come up with so far... There is something extra that I don't understand, because this function ends up / would not work to return sets that contain y and d, but leaving m arbitrary.

```
if(y == s[0]){

        if(m == s[1]){

            if(d == s[2]){

                print "day match";

                }

            } else {print "month match";}

        } else {print "year match";}

    } else {print "no match";}
```

Comment: What are your own thought about how to code this? What code have your created so far? We love to help, but we don't like to do your work for you because you are too lazy to do it yourself.

Comment: I have everything coded in my script except this function. I don't know if I understand how to do the recursion properly. I am adding an edit with my code.

Comment: Dont tag as java and javascript they are not the same thing

Answer (score 0):

It's been a very long time since I've wrote something in php, so I will suggest you in *pseudocode*, what is going on my mind :

```
$ReturnedSets = array();
   if( (!isset y) or == s[0]) {
      if( (!isset m) or == s[1]) {
         if( (!isset d) or == s[2]) {
                 $ReturnedSets[] = s;
         } else {print "month match";}
         } else {print "year match";}
   } else {print "no match";}
return $ReturnedSets;
```

I hope this pseudocode you find usefull and give you a clue how to get to working code.